# Get 3 number of data randomly and show it on blade and get another 3 data without duplicating data that already show

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have a problem where I have 9 data in a database and I want to get randomly 3 data to be inserted in 3 groups (A, B, C) and I don't want any data duplicate since it is randomly taken from the database.

This is the code in my Controller that I already tried for A, but I don't know how to get the next 3 random data for B and C without any data duplicate.

```
$A = TemporarySubject::inRandomOrder()->where('subject_type','compulsory')->take(3)->get();
$B = // i dont know how to do this
$C = // i dont know how to do this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$A = TemporarySubject::inRandomOrder()
                  ->where('subject_type','compulsory')
                  ->take(3)
                  ->get();

$B = TemporarySubject::inRandomOrder()
                  ->where('subject_type','compulsory')
                  ->whereNotIn('id', $A->pluck('id')) // <---
                  ->take(3)
                  ->get();

$A = TemporarySubject::inRandomOrder()
                  ->where('subject_type','compulsory')
                  ->whereNotIn('id', $A->pluck('id')) // <---
                  ->whereNotIn('id', $B->pluck('id')) // <---
                  ->take(3)
                  ->get();
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion, thanks man.. really appreciate it